# Adding custom component to app in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-web-components

I deployed custom lightning web component (deployed source) to org.
It was redirected to my org but that custom component is not visible in (lightning app builder)lightning experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define meta file of LWC component to expose it in different lightning experiences like app-builder. Example is as below in meta file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <masterLabel>Best Component Ever</masterLabel>
  <description>This is a demo component.</description>
  <targets>
      <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
      <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
  <targetConfigs>
      <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
          <property name="prop1" type="String" />
          <objects>
              <object>Account</object>
              <object>Opportunity</object>
              <object>Warehouse__c</object>
          </objects>
      </targetConfig>
      <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage, lightning_HomePage">
          <property name="prop2" type="Boolean" />
      </targetConfig>
  </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

> This configuration file makes the component available for all
>   Lightning page types, but restricts support on record pages only for
>   account, opportunity, and warehouse objects. The component has a
>   different set of properties defined for record pages than for app and
>   Home pages.

You can have more idea by reading [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_app_builder)

Comment: Thank you so much.Its working fine.